# Clear Animation in ViewHolder's item RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView and have some animation where I scaleup one of RelativeLayout in ViewHolder item.

**Note:** It is not the add/remove/insert animation. It starts when user interacts in ViewHolder item. Hence I am not using ItemAnimator here.

Animation works fine but it reappears (final state) in some random View item. I know it is due to reuse of items and I am clearing animation too but it didn't help.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Model model = getModelObject(position);
    ((Model) viewHolder.itemView).showItem(position);   
}
```

I am doing this in showItem

```
        relativeLayout.clearAnimation();
        relativeLayout.setAnimation(null);
```

In onViewDetachedFromWindow

```
@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    ((ItemView) holder.itemView).clearAllAnimations();
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);

}
```

ClearAllAnimations

```
    public void clearAllAnimations() {
    for (RelativeLayout layout : layoutArray) {
        optionLayout.clearAnimation();
        optionLayout.setAnimation(null);
    }
```

Here how I am animating the view

```
public AnimatorSet onDragStartAnimation(RelativeLayout group[]) {

    AnimatorSet big = new AnimatorSet();
    for (RelativeLayout relativeLayout : group) {
        ObjectAnimator scaleXSmall = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(relativeLayout, "scaleX", 1.0f, 0.85f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleYSmall = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(relativeLayout, "scaleY", 1.0f, 0.85f);

        big.playTogether(scaleXSmall, scaleYSmall);
    }

    return big;
}
```

it is not working. RelativeLayout not resetting and appearing in scaledup state in some random View Item.

**Update**

I did small experiment: Set alpha animation on ImageView in ViewHolder item like this

```
Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fadein);
imageView.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
```

and used clear animation. imageView.clearAnimation(); it worked and ImageView was visible normal when next time ViewItem appears on the screen.

But same is not working if I do this

```
alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(centerImageView, "alpha", 1.0f, 0.5f);
        alphaAnimator.start();
```

And to clear this

```
        alphaAnimator.removeAllListeners();
        alphaAnimator.cancel();
        alphaAnimator.end();
```

this didn't work. Alpha animation remains in ViewHolder image item.

Comment: Where you're calling this code?

Comment: Try to clear the animation in [onChildDetachedFromWindow()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#onChildDetachedFromWindow(android.view.View))

Comment: do I need to extend RecyclerView to do this?

Comment: Sorry i mean [onViewDetachedFromWindow()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH)), you can override it from the adapter

Comment: Didn't help... see updates

Comment: Even if you add *.setAnimation(null)*?

Comment: tried all that.... no luck

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem in this way. Everything works fine.

*GroupsViewHolder - it is custom RecyclerView.ViewHolder*

```
@Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(GroupsViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);
        //here add animation
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(GroupsViewHolder holder) {
        //here clear animation
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By inspiring from crymson's answer from [Crymson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982971/2452189) I have made little easy and useful solution using tag method of View instead setting a boolean in complicated logic of your custom adapter.

```
@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == TYPE_AD)
        ((ViewHolderForAd) holder).ivStory.setTag(false);
}


public class ViewHolderForAd extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView ivStory;
        TextView tvName;

    public ViewHolderForAd(View view) {
        super(view);
        ivStory = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivStoryImage);
        tvName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAppName);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                if (pos < 0) {
                    pos = (int) v.getTag();
                }
                customItemClickListener.onItemClicked(v, pos);
            }
        });

       //ivStory.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.pulse_story));
        ivStory.setTag(false); //Set default tag false to decrease risk of null
    }
}

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
//...Your code...
if (!(boolean) holder1.ivStory.getTag()) {
     holder1.ivStory.setTag(true);
     holder1.ivStory.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.pulse_story));
}
//...Your code...//
}
```

You can use setTag(key, object) instead of setTag(object) if you already tagged something(like position) in your imageView. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing reverse animation of all animators in onViewDetachedFromWindow.

```
@Override
public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
    if (holder.getItemViewType() == 1) ((MyItemView) holder.itemView).reverseAllAnimations();
}
```

Comment: What is reverseAllAnimations();? I can't find such method.

Comment: No method reverseAllAnimations() in view.